# JQuery is not updating <div> tag, but rather display message on a new blank page!

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning JQuery, and I'd like to isolate basic functionalities. On my 'Index" page, there is only one item, an '**AJAX.Link**' displaying the following message '**Say Hello!**". here's the mark up:

```
<div id = "helloDiv">
<% = Ajax.ActionLink("Say Hello!",
                     "Hello",
                     new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "helloDiv",
                                      OnSuccess = "AnimatedHello"
                     })

%>
</div>
```

When clicked, the link calls the Hello action method located in the Home Controller.

```
    public ActionResult Hello()
    {
        return Content("Hello World!");
    }
```

On success, the Ajax.ActionLink calls the following JQuery function:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function AnimatedHello() {
        $("#helloDiv").animate({ fontSize: "1.5em" }, 400);
    }
</script>
```

**Unfortunately**, Instead of getting the  updated in the same page (= the Index page), I rather get the "Hello World" message on a new page with the following URL (*http://localhost:51531/Home/Hello*). Of cause, there's no such page as Hello.aspx.

**Why It's showing the 'Hello World' message in new blank page? instead of updating the  on the Index page? Am I missing something?**

I'm really new to JQuery. This sample comes from the ScottGu's NerdDinner Tutorial that I tried to adapt in order to understand how JQuery works.

Here's how I referenced the libraries:

```
<head runat="server">
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Dumb question, but if you view the source, is the jQuery library referenced correctly and can you verify it is loading?

Comment: English not being my first language, I'll act as if I didn't understand what you wrote: You just called my question 'Dumb'. Where I'm located it's almost the morning. So, I'm expecting answers not insults. Other people will be nice and respectful with newbies like me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Richard, Doug was calling *his* question ("Is jQuery referenced?") dumb, not yours :)

Comment: Sorry for that! I really apology to Doug. I referenced 3 libraries "(i)jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js, (ii) MicrosoftAjax.js, and (iii) MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, first on the Index page. I then tried on the master page with no better result. But, I don't know how to check if it's loading.

Comment: Append the code snippet of how do you reference js files to your question. You could verify they are loaded with FireBug or Google Chrome JavaScript Console.

Comment: I just modified my post to include the way I reference libraries

Comment: You don't have to reference the documentation library, so you can change your jQuery reference to jquery-1.3.2.min.js and save some time and bandwidth.

Comment: I've checked (JavaScript Console) the page that's associated with the Home/Hello url, and I confirm that all 3 of those libraries are loading.

Answer (score 2):

With `Ajax.ActionLonk` helper you don't use jQuery really. This helper utilize Microsoft Ajax Library, not jQuery. And it's very probable that you don't reference this library's js files. That is why link works like a plain link.

You could achieve the same with the following jQuery code.

```
<div id = "helloDiv">
<% = Html.ActionLink("Say Hello!", "Hello") %>
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#helloDiv > a").click(function(){
            $.get(this.href, AnimatedHello);
            return false;
        });
    });

    function AnimatedHello(data) {
        $("#helloDiv").html(data).animate({ fontSize: "1.5em" }, 400);
    }
</script>
```

**Code is not tested!**

I'd like to point out several things.
- Link is generated with plain Html helper.
- Ajax functionality is added with jQuery to the link (click event).
- `return false;` statement prevents link default processing, i.e. following href.
- `AnimatedHello` function now performs additional task: filling div with response.

See documentation:
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click#fn
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype
http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val

Comment: I'm still trying to eat baby food, so I'm a little lost. Can u make it a little simpler as the one ScottGu used in his book? Otherwise I might have to go through the JQuery website and feel the same way (lost).

Comment: This code is quite simple. If you want to learn jQuery as you stated, you need to go through the jQuery website. Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to mix Microsoft Ajax Library and jQuery up. My example is pure jQuery-based.

Comment: You are right. I thinks I was just discouraged by the yesterday's succession of failures. All night long, I went through many (obvious) beginner's tutorials available on the Net, but I couldn't get any of them work. After taking a deep breath, I believe that problem might be (i) the way I've referenced the libraries and (ii) the fact that I need to understand how both Ajax and JQuery work. Matter of fact, I just checked one the books I bought "Pro MVC/APRESS -- Steve Sanderson." The author tells how to reference specifically JQuery in MVC project. I'll try & get back here